# Why is the Ucayali in Werner Herzog's 'Fitzcarraldo' flowing in the wrong direction?

Tags: fitzcarraldo

In Werner Herzog's *Fitzcarraldo*, when they move the ship from the top of the hill down to the Ucayali, the water is flowing from left to right. But according to the maps shown and the sketch drawn by Kinski in the film, it should go from right to left.

I am a little bit puzzled by this fact, as I always assumed they really dragged this ship over the hill while shooting the film. Is there any information out there on how and where the scene was shot?

Comment: Everything I've read about it, and a couple documentaries, seem to verify that they did indeed drag that ship. I don't know enough to comment on the flow of the river, though.

Comment: How certain are you it's flowing in the wrong direction? Can you give us more evidence?